# What countries can I work in to earn the highest rate, and get taxed less, to save more in two years?

Tags: careers, software

I am an Australian citizen and a senior software engineer with 12+ years of enterprise experience. What would my options be if I am solely looking to maximise my earnings in the next two years, and if I am open to work in any country that would give the maximum monetary return for the time I commit, with a focus on saving more, getting taxed less?

Appreciate your input.

Comment: You do realize you *can’t* work in most other countries without work visas and other difficulties right?

Comment: This is probably not answerable.  Salaries are likely highest in San Francisco or New York depending on the type of company.  But living expenses are also high there.  How much you can save will depend on things like what trade-offs you are willing to make.  Living in a van while working in SF will generate a lot of savings but isn’t exactly what most people would consider pleasant.

Comment: VTC - Fundamentally, this isn't a question about Workplace, this is a question about Tax law.

Comment: @TheDemonLord since my question was more along the lines of a career location move, rather than on tax law itself, I went ahead posting on workplace. I wanted to post it on a broader "careers" space but stackexchange does not seem to have one

Comment: If you just want to see big numbers on your bank statements, go to a country with a really weak currency. There you can probably receive 6-digit figures per hour (not that you would be able to buy much with it).

Comment: This question is unanswerable because it assumes that the OP can find work in that country, maintain that job throughout the two years while possibly not knowing the language(s), not making any serious cultural mistakes, and minimize the move and living expenses. Several times I considered my moving expenses and figured that moving would cost many thousands of US$. I figured that staying and finding local work was the least cost alternative.

Comment: @KavindaHewage location and tax law in said location are not inter-workplace issues - hence off topic.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Svalbard](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Svalbard,+Svalbard+and+Jan+Mayen/@77.2461211,12.137519,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x45a1cfdc4fa3c049:0x2bf373e71b35e875!8m2!3d77.8749725!4d20.9751821!16zL20vMDZ2MmI?entry=ttu)? From what I've read, almost anyone can work there, and I bet you could save a lot of money during a two year stint. You might like the adventure--one job listing for an IT/Geodetic expert (including "experience with Linux, Website development, C/C++ and/or Python experience") says **"You must be able to handle the use of firearms for self-protection due to the presence of polar bears"**:

https://karriere.no/jobb/geodesi-5420546?utm_campaign=google_jobs_apply&utm_source=google_jobs_apply&utm_medium=organic

Comment: Ha! I've read fascinating things about Svalbard including coexisting with polar bears, but I think the "ability to handle firearms" bit would fail me miserably

Comment: Keep in mind the next sunrise in Svalbard will be on Feb 16 :-). Not a good place if you don't like LONG dark winters.

Comment: get inspired by watching Arctic Void--filmed there: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9183978

Answer (score 0):

Australia is probably your best option. Moving is an expensive hassle and you can always look for remote work overseas if you want.

The best way to save is to minimise your living expenses. If you live with your parents rent free it makes a huge difference. Likewise living somewhere cheap, eating cheap etc,.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. My comparison went along with what I currently earn, in comparable other countries with lesser tax, at a general modest living standard. An additional by-product will be the exposure to different cultures and ways of life. Already considered your suggestions but the former (kinda' drastic) changes were what I was more after

Comment: Australia is one of the main places people move to for better money, even from NZ. The problem with moving is it usually takes a couple of years or more to get ahead. If you really want a culture shock then go rural. This also has the benefit of decreased living costs.